# how to place the navigation bar beneath the content view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

i am want to place the content view beneath the navigation bar. my attempts is in the image-1 below, but at run time i get something as shown in image-2

please let me know how to place the navigation bar below the content view correctly

**image-1**:

[image]

**image-2**:

[image]

Comment: you want to place navigationBar below the cell?

Comment: this is weird, you can not place the navigation bar IN the table view under the cell. what do you want to achieve?